# Find in Path text box is pre filled with random string

Tags: macos, android-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, openpgp

Android Studio / IntelliJ Find in Files pre-populates with a random string / hash / uuid / guid / fingerprint. How do I stop this from happening?
[image: pre-filled nonsense]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because OpenPGP adds a system-wide keyboard shortcut Ctrl + Shift + F. Go to System Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Services and Uncheck the OpenPGP: Insert My Fingerprint box to fix the issue.

[image: unfortunate]

Comment: See also https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/87979-gpg-keychain-shortcut-key-combination-really-anoying and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-201301.